# My php code does not receive any data in ajax call when I am on a online host

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

HTML:

```
<form  id="myForm" style="display:none" action='picture.php' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input  type="file" name="file" id="file"/><br/> 
    <input  type="submit"  id="submit"/><br/>
</form>
```

Script:

```
$('#templatemo_content_wrapper').on('click', '#change',function(){
    $("#file").trigger('click');
});

$('#file').change(function(){
    $("#submit").trigger('click');
});

$('#myForm').ajaxForm({ 
    beforeSend     : function(){
        $('#change').fadeOut(1);
    },
    UploadProgress : function(){},
    success        : function(){},
    complete       : function(){
        var split = location.search.replace('?', '').split('=')
        var id = split[1];
        $.post('profile_processor.php',{id:id},function(data){
            $('#templatemo_content_wrapper').html(data);
            checked('rel');
            checked('gpa');
            checked('student');
        });
        $('#upload_pic').fadeOut(1);
        $('#change').fadeIn(1);
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])===true){
    if(!empty($name=$_FILES['file']['name'])){
        $allowed=array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
        $file_name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$file_name)));
        $file_temp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        if(in_array($file_ext,$allowed)===true){
            cheange_profile_picture($session_user_id,$file_temp,$file_ext);
            mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `img_active`=1 where `id`=$session_user_id");
        }
    }
}
```

When I uploaded my file on *Godaddy host*, none of the AJAX calls work except one of them. AJAX call doesn't send the data into PHP script. To make it more clear if I add `die();` in the PHP at the very begging of the page, it wont affect the code at all. However if I add an `alert()` into AJAX `success` callback, it show the alert. I really don't know how to come up with a solution.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: You sure you got the spelling right for `cheange_profile_picture`? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: If you are using Google Chrome then press `F12` and go to the Network tab and you will see your AJAX calls in real time. You should get cozy with this tab if you want to avoid pulling out all of your hair with AJAX. I think Internet Explorer and FireFox support the same thing but Chrome's is the best so learn to use it and love it.

Comment: You don't post any file to your PHP. You post `{id:id}`. So the `if(isset($_FILES['file']))` is purely skipped and the PHP returns empty data. You want to test `if(isset($_POST['id']))`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- accidently i had the same typo while defining that function so that wouldn't be a problem. I already put the error reporting on but there is not any error .

Comment: @JeremyThille its because i send the picture to one php page and save to the directory then reload the page one more time so image will appear at the same time .